# Check Constraints in Object Constructor or Factory?

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am building factories for my domain objects because their constructors are becoming untidy.  My question is, should I move tests on constraints to the factory, or should I leave them in the domain object constructors?

The tests are mostly just checking that required parameters are provided before the object is instantiated, or that related objects have particular values.  If the test fails, they are generally just throwing an exception.

On one hand, I think the logic belongs in the domain object, because it's an essential part of the object.  For example, a Pet without an Name is just not valid.

On the other hand, pretty much all of what I am moving to the factory is an essential part of the domain object.  (This is a consequence of a domain object factory, right?  It breaks the domain object's encapsulation?)

It would be safer to leave it in the domain, but it is untidy.  My code would be more readable if it was in the factory, but if someone accidentally uses the `new` operator instead of the factory, I'm in trouble...

Comment: It should be the job of the domain object to determine if it is valid or not. Throw an exception in the constructor of an object if the required fields don't meet your validation rules then optionally catch them in the factory class.

Comment: Orangepill, why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments it would be much better to keep validation specific to the domain object. In that way you keep your factory free of the clutter of all of the context specific validation rules.

If you want to centralize error handling for the factory just have each of the classes that the factory creates throw an exception on an attempt to create an object that does not match the validation requirements.  The your factory can catch and deal with them.